# Текст с поля textarea

Tags: textarea, mysql

Есть поле для комментариев textarea, по идее переносы строк должны сохранятся при занесении в базу, но выводит из базы текст одной строкой, то есть не сохраняется, если после слова нажму 2 раза enter и напишу ещё что-то, всё придет как одна строка. Как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вы пробовали перед **выводом** данных прогонять их через [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php)()? Просто html игнорирует переводы строк, сколько бы их там не было.